# Determining whether the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} \frac{x(y-2)^3}{3x-5(y-2)^4}$ exists or not

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

If we approach (0,2) through the curve $\alpha:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}^2, \alpha(t) = (\frac{5}{3} (t-2)^4,t)$ when $t\to2$, then the denominator vanishes. Does this allow us to conclude that the limit doesn't exist? If so, why?

Comment: No.  The prescribed path falls outside the domain of  the given function.   Any path that you consider for the limit must in fact to stay off your curve $\alpha.$

Comment: This was answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221534/determining-whether-the-limit-lim-x-y-to0-2-fracxy-233x-5y-24

Comment: @rogermurdock  You have somehow placed a link to this same question instead of the duplicate.

Comment: I think that @rogermurdock intended [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358618/prove-existence-of-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-2-fracx-y-233x-5y-2?rq=1).